# jQuery get selected option from combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, combobox

I have a combobox like this

[image]

after that, I have a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, I want to copy the value of the combobox to an input of text. I write a jQuery code like this to get the value, then I set the value of combobox to an input of text

[image: jQuery to get value of combobox]

i check console to see the result.
[image: value]

I get the value if I check the log. But the value can't set into input text.

[image: value can't set]

But, if I make a little change in jQuery to get the key of combobox, the key can be set in the input text.

[image]

Then,in the input text I can get the key of combobox

[image: input text]

I need help for this.

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of code.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Looks to me like your input has the correct value, but that value is preceded (includes) 100s of spaces.  Consider [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxvkLsoe/).  Try `.val().trim()` when getting the value.

Comment: Your last image appears to be the same code as the code before it - obviously can't quite tell as it's not text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Please provide the HTML (not the templating code)

Simplified:

```
$("#customCheck1").on("click", function() { 
  const text = this.checked ? $("#province option:selected").text() : ""; 
  $("#current_province").val(text);
});`
```

assuming unique IDs